# To Delete And Update Photo

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables
1.blogalbum in which datas in it are

```
Id  AlbumName   CoverPhoto          CreatedDate                    Description     
1   Onam        noImage.jpg     2012-07-05 10:54:46.977            Onam is an ancient festival which still survives in modern times. Kerala's rice harvest festival and the Festival of Rain Flowers, which fall on the Malayalam month of Chingam, celebrates the Asura King Mahabali's annual visit from Patala (the underworld). Onam is unique since Mahabali has been revered by the people of Kerala since prehistory.    According to the legend, Kerala witnessed its golden era during the reign of King Mahabali. The Brahma-Vaivarta Puranam explains that Lord Vishnu wante     
2   Birds       noImage.jpg     2012-07-05 11:02:48.667         
3   Nature    gold-fish.jpg     2012-07-05 11:03:36.503
```

2.blogphoto in which datas in it are

```
    Id  AlbumId PhotoName                  AddedDate            
    29  1   Photo0364.jpg      2012-07-05 11:01:18.270          
    30  1   Photo0380.jpg      2012-07-05 11:01:35.723         
    31  1   Photo0404.jpg      2012-07-05 11:01:47.717          
    32  1   Photo0404.jpg      2012-07-05 11:02:34.457          
    33  2   f.jpg              2012-07-05 11:03:03.300          
    34  2   g.jpg              2012-07-05 11:03:12.917         
    35  3   image005.jpg       2012-07-05 11:03:45.367          
    36  3   1.jpg              2012-07-05 11:03:57.837          
    37  3   2.jpg              2012-07-05 11:04:05.580          
    38  3   na.jpg             2012-07-05 11:04:17.337          
    39  3   gold-fish.jpg      2012-07-05 11:06:29.453
```

Here from above tables when I delete any photo from second table, the field coverphoto from 1st table with name same as photoname in 2nd table must replace with an image noImage.jpg. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise updating your database schema.

Instead of a Cover photo field in table one, add BlogPhotId, with a foreign key relationship to table 2. Then you can configure it so that when the photo is deleted from table 2, the value in table 1 is set to null.

Then in application logic, display the noImage.jpg where the BlogPhotoId is null in table 1.

A query to do the update without correcting the schema would look something like:

```
SELECT @AlbumId = Album, @PhotoName = PhotoName FROM BlogPhoto WHERE Id = @Id
DELETE FROM BlogPhoto WHERE Id = @Id
UPDATE BlogAlbum SET CoverPhoto = 'noImage.jpg' WHERE AlbumId = @AlbumId AND PhotoName = @PhotoName
```

Instead of a set of queries like this, you could also consider using a trigger, and looking at the Deleted rows.

Comment: Mr.James Osborn your query meets my requirement. Thanks For that.

Comment: Surely I try your advice also. Thankyou very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with James to update your schema or just set a trigger. 
Anyways, a simple and easy way would just be to update your first table after deleting, replacing the deleted picture.

```
UPDATE blogalbum
SET CoverPhoto = 'noImage.jpg'
WHERE CoverPhoto = 'yourDeletedPicture.jpg'
```